# Reading NVARCHAR from SQL server to R

Tags: sql-server, r, encoding, type-conversion, utf-16

There is a table in the SQL Server 2012 that contains a field (Title) with UTF-16 text in in.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InfoN](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
```

This text contains non-English characters. When I fetch data via RODBC to R the non-English characters get corrupted.

```
query = "SELECT Title FROM InfoN"
db = odbcConnect(dsn)
result <- sqlQuery(db, query)
odbcClose(db)
```

the result looks like this

```
>head(title)
                                           Title
1 ??????? ???????????? ???????-?????? Han ??????
2        ???? ???????????? ?????-10 - ?????-????
3                       "1412 FORMAT 26"" 24 ??"
4                ??????? ???????? ??????????-3.4
5                                         ??????
6                              ????????? ???????
```

Is there a way to read that data without corrupting it?

Comment: can you also show your query please?

Comment: SELECT Title FROM InfoN

Comment: Can you please specify which ODBC driver (version) you are using in your DSN? Old ODBC driver do NOT support Unicode encodings which are the foundation of nvarchar columns. The solution would be to install a newer ODBC driver from Microsoft